# What is the best way to download file from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf

I have interesting task which requires me to download a dynamically generated file from a server (ASP.NET) to the client. On the client side it is just JavaScript (jQuery) and the client is able to generate a lot of parameters to customize how the data is exported.

What is the best way to do download the file from the server?  Should I use a WCF service such as what is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP) or simple page like [this one](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-download-file-from-server-using.html)?

I don't know how to download a file without reloading the page (I'm not sure that $.ajax will work in this case). Could someone please give me some direction on this topic? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is related to this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you can create the file from a handler `.ashx`

Let say that you have the file for downloading at `download.ashx` and you have some parametres to pass from your javascript, eg `download.ashx?p1=8827&p2=8831` to know what you going to create.

Then on your javascript you simple can make a redirect as

```
window.location = "download.ashx?p1=8827&p2=8831";
```

or alternative you can use the `window.open` for do the same think

```
window.open("download.ashx?p1=8827&p2=8831");
```

and your file will start the download.

Just make sure that you have set the header of attachment, and the correct contenttype on your handle eg:

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                    "attachment; filename=" + SaveAsThisFileName);
```

Simple and clear, both tested and working.

Also you may interesting on this answer: [How to handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616216/159270).

Comment: How do you do error handling? For instance, how would you handle an exception being thrown in the .ashx file?

Comment: @Steve If you have an error you throw the page not found, log the error and fix it.

Comment: @BogdanM. You short it down, send an id, not some full url. This is a different issue to solve/handle, that you can not avoid - but is not that hard.

Comment: I was just wondering if the suggested solution remains the best. Most modern browsers have enabled pop-up blockers. So the redirection that is proposed here as the accepted method I think is not the rightest solution. I face the same problem so I would appreciate if anyone could give his/her feedback.

Comment: @GrigoriosKoulouras the `window.location` is not pop-up anything and starts the download.