# file download by calling .ashx page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ashx

I'm requesting .ashx page from Master page client side script (Jquery) which has a code to download a PDF file. When I debug it, I can see the execution of "file download" code but file  is not downloading.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "FileDownload.ashx",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) { }
} );

public class FileDownload : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

        string fileName = "BUSProjectCard.pdf";
        string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Print/");
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
        context.Response.TransmitFile(filePath + fileName);
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: this post might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999607/download-and-open-pdf-file-using-ajax

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your file is downloading, but you get it on javascript, on the `data` parameter of your call because you call it with Ajax.

You use a handler - so ajax not needed here, and the most easy thing to do using javascript is that:

```
window.location = "FileDownload.ashx?parametres=22";
```

or with a simple link as

```
  <a target="_blank" href="FileDownload.ashx?parametres=22" >download...</a>
```

Ah, and send the parameters via the url, you can not post them that way.

You can also read: [What is the best way to download file from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912164/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-file-from-server)

Comment: This is very helpfull, you are right with the answer. After few minutes trying to download a file in .ashx with a json call in the client, I didn't get the file in any way.

Comment: @Aristos this works perfectly. But I need to show the message if something goes wrong at the server side.. How would I do that? Messages "Something went wrong or File Not found"

Comment: @Prabu at the server side you only can log the error - relative easy inside the handler. Find or write a log class...

Comment: @Aristos But I need inform the client if something goes wrong