# How to display a file in a folder without showing physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use .NET Framework. I have a files in a folder. Physical path like:

```
https://example.com/folders/123aaa.jpg
```

And I have a button to redirect this link. But I don't want to show this path.
I want user to see like:

```
https://example.com/display.aspx
```

Is there any way to do that?

```
<asp:Button ID="eg" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Save"

private void save(int i)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView7.Rows[i];
    string sid = row.Cells[0].Text;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("xxx", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", sid);         
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rd.HasRows)
    {
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            string url = rd[0].ToString();
        }
    }

    Response.Redirect(url,false); 
}
```

Comment: Use e.g. [ASHX handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12087040/107625).

Comment: When the user requests `display.aspx`, how will you know what file to return?  Is there only one possible file?  If so then you can just stream the file to the user from within your `display.aspx` code.

Comment: i have only one path. it was just an example. I get id from my gridview and getting link from database. so there is only one file.

Answer (score 2):

No, your client has to send *some* form of identifier. Otherwise, how will your server know which file they requested? And any identifier that an browser sends, can be inspected by the user.

So you're trying to apply security through obscurity.

If you don't want clients to know the folder name `folders`, or the file name `123aaa.jpg`, you'll have to obscure this through a mapping, for example a large random name that maps to the actual file path.

You can do this by for example saving the random names and actual paths in a database, and create a handler that looks up the file:

```
/images.ashx?file=abc-123-456
```

Then that ASHX handler looks up the file with the name `abc-123-456` in the database, and writes the actual file to the response.

Comment: I agree the way you say. I generally use tokens for per user to display. I just wondered is there any easy way to hide physical path. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Isn't an ASHX handler more lightweight than an ASPX page?

Comment: @Uwe absolutely right, no need for a page lifecycle when you're going to return a file.