# How to download or upload files using javascript(Client side scripting)

Tags: javascript, c#, file-upload, download

I'm using the below code in javascript for downloading or uploading a file from network.

```
$(document).ready(function DirectoryCopy(sourceDirName, destDirName, copySubDirs, test) {
        debugger;
        try {
            var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo.ctor(sourceDirName);
            var directory_stop = dir.get_Name();
            var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
            if (!dir.get_Exists()) {
                throw $CreateException(new System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException.ctor$$String("Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " + sourceDirName), new Error());
            }
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(destDirName)) {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory$$String(destDirName);
            }
            if (test == true) {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory$$String(destDirName + "\\" + "Complete");
            }
            var files = dir.GetFiles();
            for (var $i2 = 0, $l2 = files.length, file = files[$i2]; $i2 < $l2; $i2++, file = files[$i2]) {
                var temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine$$String$$String(destDirName, file.get_Name());
                file.CopyTo$$String$$Boolean(temppath, true);
            }
            if (copySubDirs) {
                for (var $i3 = 0, $l3 = dirs.length, subdir = dirs[$i3]; $i3 < $l3; $i3++, subdir = dirs[$i3]) {
                    var temppath = System.IO.Path.Combine$$String$$String(destDirName, subdir.get_Name());
                    DirectoryCopy(subdir.get_FullName(), temppath, copySubDirs, false);
                }
                return dirs.length;
            }
            return files.length;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            var path = "d:\\tempnew\\MyTest.txt";

            var sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(path);
            try {
                sw.WriteLine$$String(ex.toString());
            }
            finally {
                sw.Dispose();
            }

            return 0;
        }
    });
```

But I am getting an error on

```
 var dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo.ctor(sourceDirName);
```

as    **"System is not defined"**

I'm passing values from code behind as shown below.

```
 TextBox1.Text = @"\" + "\\10.66.3.82" + @"\" + "ipadqc" + @"\" + "IPAD Titles" + @"\" + JobName.Text + @"\" + Issue.Text;


    string Macid = (string)(Session["Name"]);

    string path = "D:" + @"\" + "Ipad Download" + @"\" + Macid + @"\" + Process.Text + @"\" + JobName.Text + @"\" + Issue.Text;
    string a;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "script", a = "DirectoryCopy('" + TextBox1.Text + "','"+path+"', true, true);", true);
```

please correct me if i'm wrong or please let me know if there is any better option to do it.

Comment: Where do you expect `System` to come from? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @FelixKling i dont really but i simply convert c# code to Javascript.

Comment: Well, C# and JavaScript two completely different languages :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.IO is a .Net thing, not a javascript thing.

For downloading files using JS, there are plenty or questions like this on Stack Overlow already. [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912164/what-is-the-best-way-to-download-file-from-server)

As far as uploading goes, the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file) pretty much sums it up.